# Javascript bookmarklet that highlights specific word

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a JavaScript bookmarklet that will simply highlight a specific word. This word will be static and I do not want input from the user. As an example, I would want this to highlight the word "test" on the current page. I only need the first instance.

Additional and likely unnecessary information: This will actually be looking at the source code of the page, which I have set up and working. I am using the following to open the source in the current tab:

```
javascript:window.location = "view-source:" + window.location.href;
```

I am hoping to amend this with a script that will then highlight the instance of the word "test". I appreciate any help. Searches have shown how to prompt a user for a term and then run it to Google, but not to simply highlight it on the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this thing can be done with [String.replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method. You can replace occurrences of the needed word with this word wrapped in a span tag with some class (`<span class="highlight">word</span>`).

Also, such methods as [String.indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), [String.substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) and [HTMLElementObject.innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) might be useful as well.

UPD: It seams that there are a bunch of ready solutions in the Internet. For example, Google with this query: "[js highlight word -jquery](https://www.google.com/search?q=js%20highlight%20word%20-jquery)" lead to these pages:

- http://javascript.about.com/library/blhilite2.htm
- http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/highlight-search-results-with-js/
- and many others.